# Oracle select query to filter rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

Say I have a table with the following values

```
id (PK) a_num  a_code effect_dt  expire_dt
32      1234   abcd   01/01/2015 05/30/2015
9       1234   abcd   06/01/2015 12/31/2015
5       1234   efgh   01/01/2015 05/30/2015
14      1234   efgh   06/01/2015 12/31/2015
```

How can I select just one record from `a_num`,`a_code` pair. Either Id's 1,3 or 2,4? There may be scenarios where there are more than 2 records for a `a_num`,`a_code` pair.

**UPDATE** - ID will not necessarily always be in order, it is just a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you rows 1 and 3

```
Select * from (
   Select * , Row_number() Over(Partition by a_num, a_code order by id) r_num from Your_Table ) result
Where r_num = 1
```

Just use `DESC` in order by and you will get rows 2 and 4

```
Select * from (
   Select * , Row_number() Over(Partition by a_num, a_code order by id desc) r_num from Your_Table ) result
Where r_num = 1
```

Comment: What if id is not necessarily always going to be in order?

Comment: in that case you can use Effect_dt instead of ID
It completely depends on which order you need.  You can just change the column name accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the [`row_number`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) window function:

```
SELECT id, a_num, a_code, effect_dt, expire_dt
FROM   (SELECT id, a_num, a_code, effect_dt, expire_dt,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a_num, a_code
                                  ORDER BY 1) AS rn
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```